# When should a variable be defined for currentDB and DBEngine.workspaces(0)?

Tags: vba

In most vba code I see that instead of simply using `currentDB.doSomething` and `DBEngine.workspaces(0).doSomething`, variables are defined.

```
Dim DB as Database
Dim WS as workspace
set DB = currentDB
set ws = DBEngine.workspaces(0)
```

Why?

What if the database **changed** after I defined the variables?

```
Set rsTable = DB.OpenRecordset(TableName)
Call rsTable .AddNew
...
rsTable .Update
```

If I use the variable `DB` later in code will it have the correct data in it, 
or should I in this case not define a variable for `DB` and use `currentDB` instead?